# Neo4j Error: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases, nosql

I am trying to build and consume a neo4j DB. Below, is the code which Im using to create a DB.

```
String graphDbPath = "C:/Users/abcd/parseJSON2GraphDB";
            GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
            GraphDatabaseService graphDb = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(graphDbPath);  

            try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
                // Perform DB operations                

                Node javaNode = graphDb.createNode();
                javaNode.setProperty( "name", "Duane" );

                Node scalaNode = graphDb.createNode();
                scalaNode.setProperty( "name", "Nickull" );

                tx.success();
            }
            graphDb.shutdown();

            System.out.println("Created Successfully");
```

The error which I get when running it is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, C:/Users/abcd/parseJSON2GraphDB
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.lambda$createDatabaseCreator$0(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:183)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:65)
    at com.idml.synquesgen.Test.createDb(Test.java:48)
    at com.idml.synquesgen.Test.main(Test.java:38)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@4a622941' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method: org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.IndexWriterConfigs.standard()IndexWriterConfig/invokeStatic
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.WritableDatabaseLabelScanIndex.<init>(WritableDatabaseLabelScanIndex.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanIndexBuilder.build(LuceneLabelScanIndexBuilder.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.getLuceneIndex(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newInstance(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.newInstance(LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method: org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.IndexWriterConfigs.standard()IndexWriterConfig/invokeStatic
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:483)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene54/Lucene54Codec
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:962)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:987)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1390)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1746)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene54.Lucene54Codec
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Any pointers as to what is causing it?

From quick searches, I tried few solutions:
 1)  Check if any instances of Neo4J already running.
 2)  Changed the neo4j version (via maven)

Nothing has worked until now.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace clearly mentions

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene54.Lucene54Codec

So be sure to have `lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.0.jar`, `lucene-codecs-5.5.0.jar` and `lucene-core-5.5.0.jar` on your classpath. (assuming you're on Neo4j 3.0.x)

Or, as a more easy one use http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j/3.0.6 as your single dependency which should pull in all other required dependencies transitively.